# What is the best way to get the conflicting lines from merge scenarios with JGit?

Tags: java, git-merge, jgit, merge-conflict-resolution

I am performing all the merge scenarios of a project (as follows in the snippet) with `JGit`, but they execute only the first time. In a second execution, the `getMergeScenarios()` returns a empty list.

```
List<RevCommit> list = getMergeCommits();   

for (RevCommit mergeCommit : list) {
    RevCommit leftParent = mergeCommit.getParent(0);
    RevCommit rightParent = mergeCommit.getParent(1);

    CheckoutCommand ckoutCmd = git.checkout();
    ckoutCmd.setName(leftParent.getName());
    ckoutCmd.setStartPoint(leftParent);
    ckoutCmd.call();

    MergeCommand mergeCmd = git.merge();
    mergeCmd.setCommit(false);
    mergeCmd.include(rightParent);
    MergeResult mResult = mergeCmd.call();

    if(mResult.getMergeStatus()==MergeStatus.CONFLICTING){
        // do whatever I want
    }

    // reset the index and work directory to HEAD
    Git.wrap( repository ).reset().setMode( ResetType.HARD ).call();
}
```

I also tried using `repository.writeMergeCommitMsg( null );` and `repository.writeMergeHeads( null );` to erase the result of the conflicting merges, so I could execute a new merge. However, I have got the  same result: an empty list in the following executions of the `getMergeCommits()`. It seems that the info concerning the existence of merges have been erased.

What should I do so I could run as much times as I want? Searching for the answer I came to the feeling that I should do something similar to a `git merge --abort` or . Is that available in `JGit`? What am I missing in the above snippet or what is the best way to get the conflicting lines from merge scenarios with JGit?

Comment: `MergeResult#getConflicts()` should do the trick, but I kinda found a bug in the `MergeResult#getConflicts()`. There is a [open change](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/71232/) waiting for review in JGit Gerrit.